# How to pass a generic collection from one page to another?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working in Asp.net.

In Page1.aspx, I have

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Person> lstPerson = new List<Person>();
        lstPerson.Add(new Person { Name = "N1", Age = 20 });
        lstPerson.Add(new Person { Name = "N2", Age = 30 });      

        Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx?Param=" + lstPerson);
    }
```

And in Page2.aspx, I have

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["Param"] != null)
            {
                var xx = Request["Param"];
            }
        }
    }
```

I know that, it is returning a string (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Person] for xx value).

How can I get the object back in Page2.aspx?

N.B.~ I cannot use Session(it's a restriction).But any other mechanism will do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can not use session then , serialize your object , store into some storage  and de serialize it when the page load

see [object Serialization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1789/Object-Serialization-using-C)

1- Create a table in your database , which has atleast 2 columns one for ID (can be auto generate) and another for  storing object graph as BLOB

2- Serialize the objectgraph using memory stream

3- Save the object graph into the table created in step 1

4- Get the ID of saved object

5- Pass the ID as QueryString

6- On other page retrieve the ID , load the objectgraph from DB and de serialize to get the object back.

If use Application object , it may be lost if your worker process recycled and if its expactable to use then use Application object but don't forget to remove the object when you  don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

In this situation, we can use HttpContext with Server.Transfer

http://odetocode.com/articles/111.aspx

Also, try viewstate with cross page post back

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37753/Access-ViewState-Across-Pages

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I am sorry. I didn't read end of your question. Is it possible to use ViewState?

**Old answer:**

You can use Session

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Person> lstPerson = new List<Person>();
    lstPerson.Add(new Person { Name = "N1", Age = 20 });
    lstPerson.Add(new Person { Name = "N2", Age = 30 });      

    Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx?Param=" + lstPerson);

    Session["listOfPersons"] = lstPerson;
}
```

And in Page2.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Session["listOfPersons"] != null)
        {
            List<Persons> personList = Session["listOfPersons"] as List<Persons>;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Application` to pass the list from one page to another

See this example:

**Page1.aspx**

```
List<Person> lstPerson = new List<Person>();
lstPerson.Add(new Person { Name = "N1", Age = 20 });
lstPerson.Add(new Person { Name = "N2", Age = 30 });

Application.Add("Persons", lstPerson);

Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx");
```

**Page2.aspx**

```
 if (Application["Persons"] != null)
 {
    List<Person> lstPerson = (List<Person>)Application["Persons"];
 }
```

Comment: No, application is global. Another request will override Persons.

Answer (score 0):

We can use HTTP context as

on page 1

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var lstPerson = new List<Person>();
            lstPerson.Add(new Person { Name = "N1", Age = 20 });
            lstPerson.Add(new Person { Name = "N2", Age = 30 });

            Context.Items["WebForm1List"] = lstPerson;

            Server.Transfer("Page2.aspx");

        }
```

on page 2

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
               var list = Context.Items["WebForm1List"] as List<Person>;

                if (list != null)
                {
                    foreach (Person s in list)
                    {
                        Response.Write(s.Name + "__" + s.Age);
                    }
                }  
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use `Server.Transfer("Page2.aspx")` instead of `Response.Redirect`, then you can use the `PreviousPage` object on your second page to transfer the data from the first page.

So on Page1.aspx.cs, make `List<Person> lstPerson` a public class field.

Then in Page2.aspx.cs, add the C# equivalent of this code to your `Page_Load` event handler (sorry for the VB, I don't know the C# syntax) :

```
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            If Not PreviousPage Is Nothing Then
               Dim pp As Page1 = DirectCast(PreviousPage, Page1)
               Dim lstPerson as List (of Person) = pp.lstPerson 
               ' use lstPerson as needed...
            End If
        End If
```

The nice thing about this approach is that you can use any .NET object without serialization.